# How to hide python message in terminal

Tags: python, image-processing

I'm using python module IPTCInfo3, and every time I export data I get this message in terminal.

```
Marker scan hit start of image data
```

What to do to hide this message? I need terminal clean.

Comment: By using, are you importing it into your own script? You could find that string in the module (use the `__file__` attribute on the imported module to find where it is) and see how its output. If its through the logging module, you may be able to supress its output. Otherwise, check and let us know how its written.

Comment: Long story short, answer is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I refer to the source code [here](https://github.com/jamesacampbell/iptcinfo3/blob/a9cea6cb1981e4ad29cf317d44419e4fd45c2170/iptcinfo3.py#L37), [here](https://github.com/jamesacampbell/iptcinfo3/blob/a9cea6cb1981e4ad29cf317d44419e4fd45c2170/iptcinfo3.py#L734-L736) and [here](https://github.com/jamesacampbell/iptcinfo3/blob/a9cea6cb1981e4ad29cf317d44419e4fd45c2170/iptcinfo3.py#L762-L768), you can try:

```
logging.getLogger("iptcinfo").setLevel(logging.ERROR)
```

after importing the module